# Determine all processes running by root with 2 columns showing: pid,cmd

Tags: linux, process, ps

What I did: 
`ps -ax -o pid,cmd,user | grep root` but this shows me on 3 columns showing the root inclusive, how do I eliminate the "root" column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by asking `ps` to filter:

```
ps -u root -o pid,cmd
```